# A correct hierarchy for a Shape model

Tags: oop

If I had to create a OOP model for a geometric Shape hierarchy which would be the best considering also a Point class?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you going to use Shapes for? What behaviours should they have in common and how should their behaviours differ?

Comment: I'd like to model a system with 2d shape  (circle, rectangle, etc.) 3d shape (sphere, etc.)

Comment: xdevel2000: Yes, but what is the system for? OO Modelling is an activity that should be completely driven by the behaviours that you are interested in. It is impossible and would be pointless to model everything about the real world in an OO design, you need - and should - only model what is important to you. To this end, you need to determine the purpose of the system which you are designing.

Comment: @Charles: oh, nothing special. my goal is just to build a simple system with 2D and 3D geometric shapes and test it.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I can make myself any clearer. What is your "simple system" supposed to do? What behaviours are you going to test?

Answer (score 0):

What about using java.awt.Shape ?

Comment: Yes but I want to create one for educational purposes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely encapsulate the idea of a shape, it should not be a hierarchy, as there are an infinite number of shapes in the universe.  Instead, it should just be one Shape class.  It should consist of a series of lines and curves.  Then, you can have methods to check if it conforms to particular shape definitions, e.g. `IsCircle()`, `IsSquare()` etc...

You could also have methods and/or constructors that set it to a particular type of shape.

Answer (score 0):

All shapes can probably implement an `IShape` interface. `IShape` would require an `Area()` method, and a `IsIntersectingWith(IShape otherShape)` method. This simplistic view though raises some other questions about how you will implement dynamic dispatch (triangle/triangle intersection requires a different algorithm from triangle/segment).

This of course is assuming you actually need this functionality. Assuming a graphics oriented shape library, you can define transformations like `Rotate`, `Translate`, `Scale`. You could also enforce the use of `Union`, `Intersect` or whatever other set operation (but those two can express everything you might need).

You can also base things towards computational geometry and provide method functions that convert any `IShape` into a `Polygon`.

My point is, the functionality that can be enforced through an `IShape` should follow the expected use. If you don't have any expected use (since its educational to start with) you should make the use as part of the exercise itself, or as a discovery field (how about this use, or that use, can we express all this functionality in one interface or should we split it into many)